# New drivers, now switchable graphics won't work

Tags: windows, switchable-graphics, amd-vision

I have an ASUS notebook with dual AMD/ATI graphic cards.

Before I've been able to switch individual programs in the Vision Control Center from high performance to energy saving and the other way around. But today I updated the drivers using the AMD Mobility to version 12.10, and now every time I try to configure switchable graphics it either shuts down or does not come up at all.

I have a new menu item called *Global Switchable Graphics* settings though. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Which model numbers of the integrated GPU (the one in the processor) and the discrete GPU do you have? The Catalyst 12.10 release doesn't support HD4000 and older GPUs. If you have a HD4000 based (R700) in the CPU and a HD5000 or later (R800) in the discrete card, or the reverse, this could happen. Only one version of Catalyst can be loaded at a time.

Comment: Also, see [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6395/amds-1211-mobility-catalyst-enduro-hotfix-mostly-included) as you may be included in the "Enduro" situation, not sure.

Comment: It sounds the `AMD Mobility` version you supported does not support your card. I would roll back the software and install the version you had.

Comment: My integrated model is a Radeon HD 6520G and the second card is a 7670M, i was checking the system information in the Vision Center and it does not seem to detect the 7670m card. I actually don't know which version to roll back too, so if anyone knows which version supports switchable graphics that would be great. The strange part is, that while testing out some Borderlands 2, it actually feelt abit smoother than before.

Comment: Okay, dubble checked and found that the 7670m card is being detected so scratch that. My bad.

Comment: Shogun 2 also ran alot more smoothly than before, maybe the individual selection of programs has just been replaced by the global switchable option. It was kind of clunky having to set them all individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found why we lost this "Configure Switchable graphics" screen. With the 12.10 release, AMD introduced the Enduro technology to improve switchable graphics settings. This enduro tech includes a new screen to configure 3d graphics for each application. However, support seems limited only to certain products...

From the release notes:

> AMD Catalyst Mobility support for AMD Enduro™ Technology
>
> AMD Catalyst Mobility now includes support for AMD Enduro™ Technology.
>   AMD Enduro Technology is currently supported on **all notebook Intel®
>   IvyBridge platforms and AMD Comal platforms** that support the AMD
>   Radeon HD 7900M, 7800M, 7700M – additional products will be supported
>   in future Catalyst releases.

My ASUS laptop is using a first generation AMD A6 APU 3420M, which is the **sabine** platform and not yet supported it seems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This seems most likely to be the case with my platform. Since the global settings work i'll just keep these drivers and hope my platform gets support soon. My games seems much more fluid with these drivers. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem! I reverted back to 12.8 and my "configure switchable graphics" screen is working again...

Comment: In case something goes wrong, which it always does, it seams!  You don't happen to have a link for that 12.8 download? The release notes for those drivers says it doesn't support switchable enabled notebooks?Thanks again!

Comment: You can get the 12.8 here : [catalyst 12.8 drivers](http://benchmark3d.com/amd-catalyst-12-8-whql) Be sure to use the mobility link. I guess by changing the "per application" settings screen and make it work for those newer "switchable graphics" laptop, they broke backward compatibility with older platforms that worked just fine before. I submitted an issue on amd driver feedback page. I'll update here if they answer me...good luck!